Override JSON Parser in fetch
I am writing a golang program, that sends large int64s, but the integers lose precision due to JS storing them internally as float64s. I found the json-with-bigint library, but I am not sure how to use the library's JSONParser function with fetch().
My code looks like this (it's a method in VueJS):
        fetchList() {
            console.log("fetchList called");
            const url = "/List"
            fetch(url, { 
              credentials: "same-origin",
             })
            .then(response => 
                response.json().then(data => ({
                list: data,
            }))
            .then(res => {
                this.servers = res.servers;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err)));
            console.log(this.list);
        },

Any ideas here? I am simply not well versed in JS enough to do this on my own.

I have not used custom deserialization myself, but this looks like a promising tutorial: https://eduardoboucas.com/posts/2020-02-04-custom-json-serialisation-deserialisation/

@PeterB AFAIK is not possible to supply a reviver to Response.json(); and even if you use a reviver with JSON.parse, it receives the already parsed values; it is a value transformer, not a decoder. There is no way in vanilla JS to intercept parsing of a number and parse it as a bigint instead. You could only do it if bigints were encoded in the JSON as strings, not numbers. The only way to parse a JSON number as a bigint is exactly what OP is doing, using an entirely different JSON decoder.

However, if OP can change their JSON generating code, to produce e.g. "42n" or ["bigint", "42"], or similar instead of just 42, then using a reviver would be possible, likely faster than using an entire alternative library written in JavaScript.

What's a reviver?

Reviver is the second argument to JSON.parse. Read the docs here, but basically it is a callback that JSON.parse will invoke in order to "revive" each value; for example turning a specially formatted JSON-compatible value into an object that could not be represented directly in JSON, like datetimes (or, indeed, bigints). This is the method Peter B's link uses.

Simple: don't use Response.json(). Instead, get the body, then parse it yourself. I.e. instead of
response.json().then(data => ({
  list: data,
}))

use
response.text().then(body => ({
  list: JSONParse(body),
}))


Thank you for the solution! I am sure others may find this useful too!

You can also always encode large ints as strings on the backend and parse them out on the front.
